# Error running 'Cedar' unit tests from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, cedar-bdd

I'm using the cedar testing framework and trying to run the tests from command line.
The build crashes with this error:

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x6c5c6c0 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 2}, {
reason = "Failed to create file; code = 2";
}
```

The tests run from xcode without any problems, I just can't get them to work from command line.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Unit-Tests and Core Data:

First I ran into "Can't find model for store". I fixed this using this thread: [Error running 'Cedar' unit tests from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363319/error-running-cedar-unit-tests-from-command-line)

Second I got the same error: "Failed to create file; code = 2"

Then I looked at the URLs and saw that:

The URL for the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and the NSManagedObjectModel are quite diffrent. But only when I do Unit-Testing and only after fixing the first error.

Usually the model is in "/some/path/<DataModelFile>.app/<DataModel>.momd/
The sqlite is in "some/path/Documents/<SQLiteFile>.sqlite

So I use the following code to get the correct URLs in both testing and running:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSURL *modelURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"WinNav" withExtension:@"momd"];

basePath = @"";
NSArray *arr = [modelURL pathComponents];
for (int i=0; i<[arr count]-2; i++) {
    basePath = [basePath stringByAppendingString:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
    if (i > 0) basePath = [basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
}
NSLog(@"modelURL: %@", modelURL);

NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/Locations.sqlite"]];
```

If I remember right then I had to create the "Documents" folder where the sqlite file is stored.

Any comments / suggestions if this works for you or how to do it better are appreciated.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. Small detail, you need to add Documents/Locations.sqlite without / in front.